# PATH variable not function for hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop

I installed hadoop in the following path,
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2

```
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop
```

contains the executable file "hadoop"

Now, I set my $PATH variable in .bashrc, and I did a echo $PATH, I get

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/:
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/bin:
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/sbin
```

i did some formatting here. When I run bin/hadoop, i get "No such file or directory", but when I run hadoop, i get the expected result.

Not sure what I did wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because hadoop as you declared in your PATH variable is not on the bin directory but here :

```
/home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop
```

so to run bin/hadoop you'll have to be in /home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2 directory.

the hadoop command is working for you thanks to your declaration in the PATH variable

If you want to make the command available for all users consider moving the folder to /opt for example.

and if using debian or a debian based distro take a look at this command

http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives

Im confused as what you want to achieve though. Since when you run hadoop you get to the expected result.

Comment: but /home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/ is already in my PATH variable, I should be able to call bin/hadoop directly,  which refers to /home/myname/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop

Comment: by bin/hadoop you mean you are in / and type bin/hadoop ?

Comment: i think it doesn't matter, when i type in "bin/hadoop", the system should search $PATH and find a working match if possible

Comment: I dont think so try typing bin/anything and unless you are on / or another directory which does has a bin directory you cant. However if you want hadoop to be in your bin directory you can create a symlink or use update-alternatives, which will create a symlink

Comment: then how do you explain, i can run "hadoop" anywhere in the system

Comment: because you add it to PATH variable hadoop is not the same as bin/hadoop. with PATH you are specifying where to get executables for that bash. "PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for executable files " http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html. when you say bin/hadoop "bin" is a directory